# How to specify default subclass for Swagger / Open API discriminator

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I have a class Foo. Most of the time instances of it are Foo. There is an enum property fooType that has 100 different enum values. For 2 specific enum values, there is a corresponding subclass of Foo. For every other of the 98 values, the object is a Foo.

Jackson lets me specify a "defaultImpl" in @JsonTypeInfo to mark the default class (as Foo itself). However, I cannot find an equivalent in Swagger / Open API. The [documentation here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.3.md#discriminatorObject) is rather difficult to grok but seems to indicate that you must list each value individually, which would be an arduous task and difficult to maintain. Is there no way to provide a fallback / default type for polymorphic deserialization?